# knock out mapping plugin updating singe item in array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have an issue trying to update an item as part of an observableArray using the mapping plugin.

I have the following code

```
accounts.list = ko.mapping.fromJS(@(Html.Raw(Model.AccountsJSON)));
```

I have this bound to a table using

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: list"> ... </tbody>
```

This all works correctly, I then have the following function

```
$('#datatable').delegate(".cancelLock", "click", function() {
        var item = ko.contextFor(this).$data;
        var param = {AccountNumber : item.AccountNumber()}
        $.post('@Url.Action("cancellock","accounts")',param,function(result){
            ko.mapping.fromJSON(result,item);
            if(accounts.lockeditem() == item){
                accounts.lockeditem(0);
            }
        });
    });
```

the line `ko.mapping.fromJSON(result,item);` causes no errors, and the function continues, however it does not cause the observable to update.

I've tried changing the code to `ko.mapping.fromJSON(result,accounts.list);` (and updating my controller to return the full list) and this works correctly - the problem being that I don't want to update the entire table, I "simply" want to revert 'item' back to it's original state.

I've also tried using `item.Updated(result.Updated);` (where updated is one of the properties of the object) and this works as expected however I'd rather not manually call this on every property unless I have to.

is it possible to use `ko.mapping.fromJSON(result,item);` (or some variation of)? Am I doing something stupidly wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your intention, you can do this using a variation of `ko.mapping.fromJS` (or fromJSON) that's mentioned in the [mapping docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) under "Specifying the update target".
So I think you want this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(result, {}, item);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kR4jc/

Comment: Thanks - believe it or not I had actually tried that previously - seems I may have had an issue that was affecting it

Answer (score 0):

I updated the fiddle to reference rawgithub.com and the latest knockout.js file..

http://jsfiddle.net/kR4jc/5/

```
https://rawgithub.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js
http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js
```

This post also helped me
https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/issues/41